# Hive create external table on JSON file but select returns empty

Tags: json, hive, hiveql

I have a file of complexed JSON data

```
{"Body":"{\"metrics\":[{\"key\":\"ccu\",\"properties\":{\"ccu\":350,\"datetime\":\"2020-03-06 11:10:25\",\"domain\":\"kalic.kyotogameservers.com\",\"game\":\"kalic\",\"instance_id\":\"i-087676860cab4c92b\",\"module_name\":\"notification\",\"stack\":\"prod\",\"user\":\"undefined\"}}],\"validation\":{\"key\":\"jsadiu\",\"method\":\"shared_key\"}}","ContentType":"application/json","ProductId":"12345","Version":1}
{"Body":"{\"metrics\":[{\"key\":\"ccu6\",\"properties\":{\"ccu\":350,\"datetime\":\"2020-03-06 11:10:25\",\"domain\":\"kalic.kyotogameservers.com\",\"game\":\"kalic\",\"instance_id\":\"i-087676860cab4c92b\",\"module_name\":\"notification\",\"stack\":\"prod\",\"user\":\"undefined\"}}],\"validation\":{\"key\":\"aksdjiw\",\"method\":\"shared_key\"}}","ContentType":"application/json","ProductId":"12345","Version":1}
```

I upload the file to HDFS and then create an external table:

```
create external table hive_test.external_json_test
(Body string,
ContentType string,
ProductId string,
Version int)  
ROW FORMAT SERDE 'org.openx.data.jsonserde.JsonSerDe'
stored as textfile
location '/user/userid/tmp';
```

The 2 lines shown here are all valid json string and the create command runs without any exception.

However, when I run `select * from ...`, it returns nothing...

Why could this happen and how to build the external table and parse the json...

Comment: if it does not return rows then table location is empty. check `hadoop fs -ls /user/userid/tmp/ `

Comment: Hi @leftjoin, thanks for your reply. I had checked a few times, the directory is not empty and it has the target file which comprises json data....

Comment: Even if serde fails to parse, it should return rows with nulls. If not - something wrong with location. Try to specify full path 'hdfs://.../data_folder'